# $(this) in animate() callback but with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

[jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) explicitly state that

> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated.

Hence, this works fine:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 1,
            "top": "36px"
    }, 600, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).css({
                    "top": 0,
                        "display": "block",
                        "opacity": 0
                });
            });
    });
});
```

`$(this)`'s next sibling that is a div is first animated in, and then with a callback it is faded out again. However...!

When using a setTimeout in the fallback, this won't work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/h6E6z/).

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 1,
            "top": "36px"
    }, 600, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).css({
                    "top": 0,
                        "display": "block",
                        "opacity": 0
                });
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I need to use `$(this).next()` though, because I will be having multiple buttons on the page. How can I keep the delay of 2s but still use the `$(this)` selector?

Comment: "this" is unknown in "setTimeout". Thats the error. Change your selector.

Comment: @lin You don't say. I am asking exactly that: how can I keep the selected element in there.

Comment: @lin not unknown but refers to window object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For jQuery's animating methods, you can use `delay()`:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 1,
        "top": "36px"
    }, 600, function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).css({
                "top": 0,
                "display": "block",
                "opacity": 0
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6E6z/2/)

NOTE: The reason that `setTimeout()` didn't work for you, is because `this` isn't referring to the element that you think it is, it's referring to the `window`. To do that, you'll need to first create a reference to `this`:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6E6z/4/)

Comment: i guess you should reset style, e.g using `.removeAttr('style')`: http://jsfiddle.net/h6E6z/3/

Comment: I was thinking about using `delay` but the docs said `.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.` so I wasn't sure.  Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is to run any code after a set amount of time. `delay()` is specifically for animation methods. (Anything in the effects queue)

Answer (score 1):

Also a little bit of magic. You can bind "this" to the timeout function.

http://jsfiddle.net/h6E6z/5/

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).css({
            "top": 0,
            "display": "block",    
            "opacity": 0
        });
    });
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Comment: bind has pros and cons, but +1 for at least bringing it to the OP's attention.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just store $(this) in a variable and use it in the timeout function (I use "$" in front of variables storing a dom element - that is of course totally optional, I just like it that way...):

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 1,
            "top": "36px"
    }, 600, function () {
        var $next_div = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $next_div.fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $next_div.css({
                    "top": 0,
                        "display": "block",
                        "opacity": 0
                });
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```